# Python logging configuration file with bandersnatch on python 3.5

Tags: python, logging, python-3.5

I'm using the latest [bandersnatch 2.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bandersnatch) with python 3.5 to create a PyPi mirror. Bandersnatch has some fairly sparse documentation, but in the sample config file, it says:

```
; Advanced logging configuration. Uncomment and set to the location of a
; python logging format logging config file.
; log-config = /etc/bandersnatch-log.conf
```

So I've ready about python logging configuration, uncommented the line above and created this logging config:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=logfile

[formatters]
keys=logfileformatter

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=logfile

[formatter_logfileformatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s

[handler_logfile]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=logfileformatter
args=('/path/to/bandersnatch.log','a',10485760,5)
```

Now bandersnatch doesn't produce any output to stdout any more, and the log file I've specified has been created, but nothing is being logged.

I've tried varying combinations of NOTSET and DEBUG for both log levels specified, but nothing has been logged yet when I run bandersnatch.

Any ideas? All the other issues I've seen about this have been programming errors or people forgetting to set the loglevel for [logger_root] for example. I don't think I've missed any of these.

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm answering too late, but could be helpful...
The issue seems to be linked to root logger, you can create a second logger as below:

```
[loggers]
keys=root,file

[handlers]
keys=root,file

[formatters]
keys=common

[logger_root]
level=NOTSET
handlers=root

[logger_file]
level=INFO
handlers=file
propagate=1
qualname=bandersnatch

[formatter_common]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(levelname)s %(message)s

[handler_root]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=common
args=(sys.stdout,) 

[handler_file]
class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=common
args=('/path/to/bandersnatch.log','D',1,'UTF-8')
#will manage one file a day
```

Hope it helps!